# Is there a way to get Livewire component name in livewire hook JS?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a global loader in my livewire application, which shows loader on message.sent livewire js hook, and hide on message.processed hook which is working fine, but now i want when specific livewire component calls loader will remain hide.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for the same question, with `component.fingerprint.name` you can get the component name.

example:

```
Livewire.hook('message.sent', (message, component) => {
    console.log(component.fingerprint.name,component,message)
})
```